# How can we use Hibernate or JPA in PIP implementation with Wso2 IS?

Tags: wso2, rbac, xacml, wso2-identity-server

I try to use Hibernate/JPA in PIP implementation of Wso2IS. when I upload my jar file with above ORM implementation then if I use hibernate then it gives error like

> An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use

I search a lot for that solution. In my another Implementation,

If I try to implement JPA instead of Hibernate then It gives me error like

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named jpa-example

I know the reason behind all above error but if I execute that all above jar with standalone application then it work find.

Can anyone help me that How I can use Hibernate or JPA in My PIP with wso2.
Thanks In advance.